# Getting the "Login" button to align centered in between username and password

Tags: html, forms, authentication

I'm creating a login form. Here's what I created:

```
<form action="loginform.php" method="POST" name="LoginForm">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="login"value="LOGIN!"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4" align="center"><a href="url">Register!</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, my code fails to make the "LOGIN!" button align in the center in between the username and password alignment. I already used the colspan tag for it, but doesn't seem to work. What needs to be done here?

Also, I want the "Register!" link to align on the farthest right side of the table. How do I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this right on text `<td colspan='3' style="text-align:right;">Register</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that tables should be used for tabular data only, but your table has some very odd row and colspans - your first row has 5 columns, second 4 and third 1 (with a rowspan of 4, even though you only have 3 rows)

I think you have got your rows and columns mixed up - try changing the rowspan to colspan and vice vera but changing the colspan to 5:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="login"value="LOGIN!"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center"><a href="url">Register!</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQHda/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using   text-align: center and text-align: right